# Getting EVP_PKEY_get1_EC_KEY' is deprecated error when installing httpd-2.4.57 with OpenSSL 3.0.7

Tags: apache, openssl

I am getting the below error when i am trying to run make command in httpd.

ab.c:769:25: warning: 'EVP_PKEY_get1_EC_KEY' is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/ssl/include/openssl/evp.h:1374): Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
EC_KEY *ec = EVP_PKEY_get1_EC_KEY(key);
^
ab.c:770:25: warning: 'EC_KEY_get0_group' is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/ssl/include/openssl/ec.h:1034): Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
int nid = EC_GROUP_get_curve_name(EC_KEY_get0_group(ec));

```
                     ^
```

ab.c:771:25: warning: 'EC_KEY_free' is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/ssl/include/openssl/ec.h:1003): Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
EC_KEY_free(ec);
^
ab.c: In function 'start_connect':
ab.c:1431:13: warning: 'BIO_set_callback' is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/ssl/include/openssl/bio.h:279): Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
BIO_set_callback(bio, ssl_print_cb);
^
/usr/local/apr/build-1/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc -std=gnu11  -g -O2 -pthread    
-o ab  ab.lo      /usr/local/apr/lib/libaprutil-1.la -lexpat /usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-1.la -luuid -lrt -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -lm -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto -luuid -lrt -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl
ab.o: In function `ssl_print_cert_info': /home/essadmin/apache-src/httpd-2.4.57/support/ab.c:676: undefined reference to` EVP_PKEY_get_bits'
ab.o: In function `ssl_print_info': /home/essadmin/apache-src/httpd-2.4.57/support/ab.c:707: undefined reference to` SSL_get1_peer_certificate'
ab.o: In function `ssl_proceed_handshake': /home/essadmin/apache-src/httpd-2.4.57/support/ab.c:757: undefined reference to` EVP_PKEY_get_id'
/home/essadmin/apache-src/httpd-2.4.57/support/ab.c:783: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get_bits' /home/essadmin/apache-src/httpd-2.4.57/support/ab.c:783: undefined reference to` EVP_PKEY_get_id'
/home/essadmin/apache-src/httpd-2.4.57/support/ab.c:740: undefined reference to `SSL_get1_peer_certificate' /home/essadmin/apache-src/httpd-2.4.57/support/ab.c:742: undefined reference to` EVP_PKEY_get_bits'
/home/essadmin/apache-src/httpd-2.4.57/support/ab.c:763: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get_bits' /home/essadmin/apache-src/httpd-2.4.57/support/ab.c:759: undefined reference to` EVP_PKEY_get_bits'
/home/essadmin/apache-src/httpd-2.4.57/support/ab.c:776: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get_bits' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make[2]: *** [ab] Error 1 make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/essadmin/apache-src/httpd-2.4.57/support'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/essadmin/apache-src/httpd-2.4.57/support'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

OpenSSL version - 3.0.7

Httpd version - httpd-2.4.57

Answer (score 0):

We were getting that error due to a library mismatch in the /usr/local/ssl/lib directory where the libcrypto.so and libssl.so was pointing to the openssl 1.1 v so files.

So, when we are compiling httpd it gets the error since its referring old libraries which were having deprecated methods. So, once we copied the correct librcypto.so and libssl.so files to the /usr/local/ssl/lib folder the error got resolved. So, after that we were able to configure OpenSSL 3.0 with Httpd 2.4.57 without any issues.

[image]